# nuxtjs axios cross origin resource sharing problem

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-authentication, axios, nuxt.js

I am currently playing around with nuxtjs and trying to integrate firebase auth rest api. But I am getting an error in the chrome console:

***Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=IHaveRemovedTheTokenWhilePostingThisToStackOverflow' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.***

How can i solve this problem?

So here is my set up

in pages/login.vue directory

```
submitLogin(){
          this.$axios.post('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=' + process.env.firebaseApiToken,
            {
            email: "abc@example.com",
            password: "123456"
            }, {
              headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/Json'
              }
            }).then((response) => {
              console.log(response.data);
          })
        }
```

in nuxtjs.config.js

```
axios: {
    credentials: false
  },
```

in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6"
  },
```

Comment: Adding `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` as a request header won't help. That is a response header and must be included by the remote server. Does the API you are trying to access support CORS?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a proxy config in nuxt.config.js

You can find an example at https://nuxtjs.org/faq/http-proxy/

Comment: I'm having the same issue and adding proxy did not work for me. Any other work arounds?

Comment: @RizaKhan can you please share the proxy config snippet ??

Comment: After adding the proxy module, make sure to also have this in nuxt.config.js: `axios: {   proxy: true }`